# Why putting -ss before -i makes it faster to capture a thubmnail image from a video file?

Tags: ffmpeg

The first command extracts a thumbnail image from a video file much faster than the second command (because I put the -ss before the -i):

```
ffmpeg -ss 10 -i input.mp4 -vframes 1 -s 320x240 output.jpg

ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vframes 1 -s 320x240 -ss 10 output.jpg
```

Why is that? Is that an intentional feature or a programming bug or something?

Comment: I guess you're the same user as http://superuser.com/users/386097/guest1564 – so I'd like to ask you to register your account. That way you have access to all your older questions, too.

Answer (score 3):

It's faster because when you put `-ss` before `-i`, ffmpeg fast-forwards until the time specified (or, to be precise, to the first key-frame after that timestamp).

If you put `-ss` after `-i`, the input audio and video will be decoded into a "raw" frame-by-frame representation. Once it gets to the timestamp specified by `-ss`, ffmpeg will actually start outputting video.

Note that if you don't copy streams and use ffmpeg 2.1 or higher, `-ss` before `-i` will be accurate, too. It used to be inaccurate (i.e., not always hitting the exact time you specified).

See also [Seeking with FFmpeg](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Seeking%20with%20FFmpeg).